# How to set property of node inside TransactionEventHandler?

Tags: java, transactions, neo4j

I'm having problems defining my own `TransactionEventHandler` in Neo4j. My goal (for simlicity here) is to bump the version property of a version node in the db each time any transaction is made.

In the following code I'm first creating a version node that should hold the current version, then register my transaction event handler, and then I create a node in the db to trigger the execution of `beforeCommit()`.

Then everything **hangs** and after a while I get [this stack trace](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=tC9DBtjg).

I'm using `neo4j-2.1.0-M02` and
this is my code:

```
public class MyTransactionEventHandlerTest {
  private static GraphDatabaseService db;
  private static MyTransactionEventHandler transactionEventHandler;

  @BeforeClass
  public static void setup() {
    db = new TestGraphDatabaseFactory().newImpermanentDatabase();

    Node versionNode = null;
    try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
      versionNode = db.createNode(DynamicLabel.label("__TransactionVersion__"));
      tx.success();
    }

    transactionEventHandler = new MyTransactionEventHandler(versionNode);
    db.registerTransactionEventHandler(transactionEventHandler);
  }

  @AfterClass
  public static void shutdown() {
    db.shutdown();
  }

  @Test
  public void commitSomething() {
    try (Transaction transaction = db.beginTx()) {
      db.createNode(DynamicLabel.label("Something")); // trigger beforeCommit()
      transaction.success();
    }
  }
}
```

My transaction event handler class:

```
public class MyTransactionEventHandler implements TransactionEventHandler<Object> {
  private Node versionNode;

  public MyTransactionEventHandler(Node versionNode) {
    this.versionNode = versionNode;
  }

  @Override
  public Object beforeCommit(TransactionData data) throws Exception {
    incrementTransactionVersion();
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void afterCommit(TransactionData data, Object state) {
  }

  @Override
  public void afterRollback(TransactionData data, Object state) {
  }

  public Node getVersionNode() {
    return versionNode;
  }

  private void incrementTransactionVersion() {
    versionNode.setProperty("transactionVersion", (Long) versionNode.getProperty("transasactionVersion", 0L) + 1);
    // this gets called many times, but doesn't return?
  }
}
```

How can I bump that node version inside the transaction event handler, without this circular error?